# how to add radius around location?

Tags: android, google-maps, radius

How can i add radius here..or dynamically ...??

```
 {
                GPSLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                GPSLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                Log.i("GPS","Lat: "+GPSLatitude+" Long "+ GPSLongitude);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location is "+GPSLatitude+" Long "+ GPSLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                googleMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude) , 16.0f) );
                }
```

Comment: do you mean to say accuracy related to?

Comment: i mean..i want to add threshold around location which i want to add/save for my gps reminder...i need to add radius dynamically or manually by giving radius in meters...

Comment: actually iam developing project on gps reminder or location reminder..i have also a problem of functionality of the application ..